# Бывает ли "кисть ноги"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сказать "кисть ноги" по аналогии с "кистью руки"? По идее, ведь тоже с пальцами.
Спасибо

Comment: Какой смешной вопрос. :D
Стопа на кисть и не похожа. Пальцы на ноге короткие и расположены впереди, а не окружают ладонь, как на руке.

Answer (score 5):

Нет, так сказать нельзя. "Кисть ноги" называется стопа.